# VB.NET only selecting in DB where there are 2 or more entries

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

When I execute this query I only get a return when there are two or more entries that equal the query.

When there is only one I am getting a null and have spent hours trying to figure it. Please help.

```
    Dim i = (From dr As DataRow In Test1DataSet.Tables("Data").Rows Select dr Where dr("S3N:").ToString.Contains(scanPNtb.Text.ToString)).Count
    For Each m3 In (From dr As DataRow In Test1DataSet.Tables("Data").Rows Select dr Where dr("S3N:").ToString.Contains(scanPNtb.Text.ToString))
        model = m3("model").ToString
    Next
    MsgBox(model & "  " & i)
```

Comment: Hi the i value was only for a test to see if it would return a 1, when there is 2 or more the i becomes 2 or X,

Comment: Where there is only 1 entry the i remains as 0

Comment: It work if there is more than 1 entry in the DB with the same criteria,

Comment: When I run with a query where there are more than one entry that matches it worked fine, I have wen over this several times, I have even went as far as copying the search string from the DB and it still will not show any return value.

Comment: When I search for the entry I have put in000-0000 where this only repeats once there is not return value, when I query 000-0001 this is in the DB 3 time's it return's i = 3.

Comment: scanPNtb.Text.ToString = 000-0000

Comment: Thanks for your help but a simple I dont know should have done it.

Comment: Wow you are getting angry because you dont understand how to awnser it and are trying to seem smarter by "Is it the clueless askers day or what?" I thought that was the point of this to ask and get help. I do not see any issues in my query and neither do you so it would seem. yet it dose not work.... I am not looking for an awnser to my question I am looking for guidance. yes I ahve broken my query down and went tru it step by step, I have even went as far as writing my own connection string. But that is not what my question I am looking for possable theorys on why it is not returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on your code using NorthWind data. It seems to work OK. Perhaps your data has some nulls in Model?

```
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT TOP 10 CompanyName, City, Region, HomePage FROM Suppliers"
    Dim dt As DataTable = Gen.GetDataTable(SQL, sConnectNorthwind)
    dgv1.DataSource = dt ' see data in grid
    dgv1.AutoResizeColumns()
    Dim sFind As String = InputBox("Find keywword:")
    Dim sOut As String = ""
    For Each m3 In (From dr As DataRow In dt.Rows Select dr Where dr("City").ToString.Contains(sFind))
        sOut &= "City: " & m3("City").ToString & vbNewLine
    Next
    Dim i = (From dr As DataRow In dt.Rows Select dr Where dr("City").ToString.Contains(sFind)).Count
    MsgBox(i & vbNewLine & sOut)
```

I used a my library to get the datatable - you can use your datatable. I used a WinForm DataGridView (dgv1) for the UI.